# Handling more than one leading zero

Tags: java

I am writing a program that calculates checksum, but needs to remove all leading zeros in the front. I know how to remove just one, but how would I remove them all?

Here's what I have so far:

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter the first 9 digits of an ISBN as an integer: ");
  ISBN = scan.nextInt();


  /******************************************************************************
  *                           Processing Section                              *
  ******************************************************************************/
  processingISBN = ISBN;     
  sum = 0;
  for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++) 
  {
     digit = processingISBN % 10;  // digit at the end
     sum = sum + i * digit;
     processingISBN = processingISBN / 10;
  }
  firstDigit = ISBN / 100000000; // grab first digit (in case of zero)

  /******************************************************************************
  *                              Outputs Section                                *
  ******************************************************************************/

   // print out check sum number, use X for 10



  if (firstDigit == 0)
  {
     System.out.print("The ISBN-10 number is 0" + ISBN);
  }
  if (firstDigit != 0)
  {
     System.out.print("The ISBN-10 number is " + ISBN);
  }

  if(sum % 11 == 1) //checks for checksum=10 
  {
     System.out.print("X");
  }
  else if (sum % 11 == 0) 
  {
     System.out.print("0");
  }
  else                    
  {
     System.out.print(11 - (sum % 11)); 
  }
```

I SHOULD MENTION: the ISBN MUST be handled as a integer, not a string.

Comment: If you're checking for the case when someone enters `"00001278126"`, you'll have a couple of problems:  first, leading zeroes indicate octal (base 8), so you'll want to capture the string instead.  Second, an integer doesn't care about leading zeroes, so 00001278126 would just come up as 1278126 anyway.

Comment: My Java stinks but process your ISBN up front using a regular expression, they rock.  Remove the leading 0's `ISBN = ISBN.replaceAll("^0", "")`.  I know that's not right but play around.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, build the ISBN as a string and then run this:

```
String yourInputAsString = "0000002514";
int yourInputAsInt;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourInputAsString);

if(m.matches()){
    yourInputAsInt = Integer.valueOf(yourInputAsString.replaceAll("^0+", ""));
    System.out.println("As String: " + yourInputAsString.replaceAll("^0+", ""));
    System.out.println("As Int: " + yourInputAsInt);

        //do check

} else {
    System.out.println(yourInputAsString);
}
```

**Output:**

> As String: 2514
>
> As Int: 2514